# Time limited Exceeded

Tags: c++

This is my code for solving Merge Interval problem from leet code link https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/
i think my code runs in O(nLogn) times but still Im getting Time limited exceeded for some of the test case. Can anyone tell me where Im going wrong.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> merge(vector<vector<int>>& intervals) {
        if(intervals.size() == 0)
            return intervals;
        sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end());
        int n = intervals.size();
        int prev = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i<intervals.size(); i = prev+1){
            if(intervals[prev][1] >= intervals[i][0] && intervals[prev][0] <= intervals[i][1]){
                if(intervals[prev][1] < intervals[i][1]){
                    intervals[prev][1] = intervals[i][1];
                    intervals.erase(intervals.begin()+i, intervals.begin()+(i+1));
                }
                else{
                intervals.erase(intervals.begin()+i, intervals.begin()+(i+1));
                }
            }else{
                prev++;
            }
        }
        return intervals;
    }
};
```

Comment: std::vector::erase is O(n), so that makes your total algorithm O(n^2) in the case where all ranges overlap.

Comment: Any solution where you are erasing elements in the container while looping over the container is bound to give time-out errors -- for each erase() call, the container has to be shrunk by one item, and that is expensive.  The trick is to find another solution where you are not erasing each time.  Use a different data structure, or structure the elements so that the erasure until the very end, where you only need one single erasure call to erase the range of (bad) values..

Comment: thankyou @PaulMcKenzie but the constraint is no extra space is allowed, the problem should be done inplace.

Comment: @RatnaKumarSingh -- You can do erasure "inplace" by partitioning off the items to erase instead of actually erasing them.  Then, as my comment suggested, you erase everything from the start of the partition until the end with one single erase() call.  The solution requires you to smartly swap items and put the items to erase at the end of the container.  See algorithm functions such as `std::remove` and `std::partition`  The "erase one-at-a-time while looping" is the naive way of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Erase is O(n), so your function is O(n*n).

If you want to avoid that, you can increment `i` instead of erasing, and not set it in the loop

Comment: Is there a better container for this scenario or another way to erase with a better time complexity?

Comment: @darclander the best thing is to not erase in the loop